# Javascript - choose random page from array BUT never show a page twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, iframe, random

I have a piece of code that randomly selects a page from an array containing an X ammount of URLs, displays it in an iframe for an X ammount of time and keeps repeating this process forever:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pages=new Array();
pages[0]="01.html";
pages[1]="02.html";
pages[2]="03.html";
pages[3]="04.html";
pages[4]="05.html";
pages[5]="06.html";
pages[6]="07.html";
pages[7]="08.html";
pages[8]="09.html";
pages[9]="10.html";
pages[x]="etc.html";

var time=33000; // this is set in milliseconds
function pageChange() {
var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*pages.length);
document.getElementById("frame").src=pages[rand];
setTimeout("pageChange()",time);
}
onload=pageChange;
</script>

<iframe id="frame" src="" width="870px" height="488px" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

Now I would like it to choose a random page, but after a page is shown it will not be shown again untill the entire array has circulated. Basically like blindly drawing cards from a deck untill all cards have been been picked once, shuffling the deck and draw again and again...

Does anyone know how it implement this in the code above? Any help or suggestions would be kindly appreciated.

[Edit:]
After the input from below the code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pages=new Array();
pages[0]="01.html";
pages[1]="02.html";
pages[2]="03.html";
pages[3]="04.html";



var shuffle = function(){
         var shuffledPages = [];

         while(pages.length > 0){
             shuffledPages.push( pages.splice(Math.floor( pages.length * Math.random() ), 1)[0] );  
         }

         return shuffledPages;
 }

var time=10000; 
var currentIndex = 0; 

function pageChange() { 
    if(currentIndex == pages.length - 1){ 
        pages = shuffle(); 
        currentIndex = 0; 
    } 
    else{ 
        currentIndex++; 
    } 

    document.getElementById("frame").src=pages[currentIndex]; 
    setTimeout("pageChange()",time); 
}

onload=pages = shuffle();
onload=pageChange;

</script>

<iframe id="frame" src="" width="870px" height="488px" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

It seems to do the trick, but something strange happens to the sequences. I noted these sequencess of 4 that were displayed: [1,2,3,4][2,1,2,1][4,3,1,2][4,2,4,3][1,3,4,2][1,1,2,3][4,2,3,1][4,4,1,2].

Answer (score 2):

IF you don't want to keep the whole array, you can use splice() to delete the elements you already choose from the array.

```
pages.splice(rand, 1);
```

That should delete the selected page from the array.

If you want to keep the whole array, you can create a "backup" array.

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep the array, because it's got to start over once a complete cycle is done. Can you tell me how I would go about coding a "backup" array?

Comment: Copy the whole array to another variable, and, before restarting, copy it back to the one you work on. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

create a shuffle function, go through the array, when you reach the end of the array, shuffle the pages again.

```
 var shuffle = function(){
         var shuffledPages = [];

         /*The first time rand is used, it will not allow you to pick the last value used last time.*/
         var rand = Math.floor((pages.length - 1) * Math.random());

         while(pages.length > 0){
             shuffledPages.push( pages.splice( rand , 1)[0] );  
             rand = Math.floor(pages.length * Math.random());
         }

         return shuffledPages;
 }
```

and you can call it like this:

```
 pages = shuffle();
```

So then you can write in the rest of the code:

```
var time=33000; 
var currentIndex = 0; 
var lastValue = null;

var pageChange = function() { 
    if(currentIndex == pages.length - 1){ 
        pages = shuffle(); 
        currentIndex = 0; 
    } 
    else{ 
        currentIndex++; 
    } 

    document.getElementById("frame").src=pages[currentIndex]; 
    setTimeout("pageChange()",time); 
}

pageChange();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66589/discussion-on-answer-by-michal-paszkiewicz-javascript-choose-random-page-from).

Comment: Ok, so it's working really well now thanks to your great input. I have a follow-up question: Is it possible to create a pauze/continue function, so after a mouseclick (button) 1 page can be frozen and displayed until a user clicks again and the pageChange function continues?

Comment: Set `val paused = false`, have an onclick event that changes it to true and you can check before setTimeout `if(paused){....}`. Then onclick for continue, click `pageChange()` again. If you have any further questions, please create a new question!